# Centered Absoloute div to big

Tags: html, css

my problem is that I have 2 divs but it should also support a min screen resolution of 1000px but in this scenario it pushs me 143px out of the viewport (scrollbar appears) (643 width) because it's first positioned left:50% and then left:-50%. Any Idea how I can solve it. It's a little harsh to explain, so I attached a screenshot.

```
<div id="outter">
 <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
#outter{
position: absolute;
height: 350px;
width: 643px;
margin: -245px auto;
left:50%;
z-index: 3;
}

#inner {
position: relative;
left: -50%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try it with: responsive webdesign

Comment: oh damn, im so stupid - ur totally right

Comment: should I answer with responsive webdesign or?

Comment: yep, you gave the right hint - i had a total brainlaag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the field of Web design and development, we’re quickly getting to the point of being unable to keep up with the endless new resolutions and devices. For many websites, creating a website version for each resolution and new device would be impossible, or at least impractical. Soo they fictional **responsive webdesign**, which in this case is the solution. Good Work :)